# Switching User Management in Spring Boot

Tags: redis, spring-boot, spring-session

I tried the example application in Spring documentation about user switching, but I tried to implement it in Spring boot, I added the filter and in the configure method I added the filter before the BasicAuthenticationHanlder. The code is as follows. The redis session is working fine, but what I want is user switching in the same browser. I couldn't find a better way to do this in spring boot. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

```html
public class DemoAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoAuthenticationFilter.class);
   
 @Override
 public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

 @Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
   throws IOException, ServletException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  

     
        String authValid = "";
        
             
     HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

  // tag::HttpSessionManager[]
  HttpSessionManager sessionManager =
    (HttpSessionManager) httpRequest.getAttribute(HttpSessionManager.class.getName());
  // end::HttpSessionManager[]
  SessionRepository<Session> repo =
    (SessionRepository<Session>) httpRequest.getAttribute(SessionRepository.class.getName());

  String currentSessionAlias = sessionManager.getCurrentSessionAlias(httpRequest);
  Map<String, String> sessionIds = sessionManager.getSessionIds(httpRequest);
  String unauthenticatedAlias = null;

  String contextPath = httpRequest.getContextPath();
  List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
  Account currentAccount = null;
  for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : sessionIds.entrySet()) {
   String alias = entry.getKey();
   String sessionId = entry.getValue();

   Session session = repo.getSession(sessionId);
   if(session == null) {
    continue;
   }

   String username = session.getAttribute("username");
   if(username == null) {
    unauthenticatedAlias = alias;
    continue;
   }

   String logoutUrl = sessionManager.encodeURL("/logout", alias);
   String switchAccountUrl = sessionManager.encodeURL("/", alias);
   Account account = new Account(username, logoutUrl, switchAccountUrl);
   if(currentSessionAlias.equals(alias)) {
    currentAccount = account;
   } else {
    accounts.add(account);
   }
  }

  // tag::addAccountUrl[]
  String addAlias = unauthenticatedAlias == null ? // <1>
    sessionManager.getNewSessionAlias(httpRequest) : // <2>
    unauthenticatedAlias; // <3>
  String addAccountUrl = sessionManager.encodeURL(contextPath, addAlias); // <4>
  // end::addAccountUrl[]

  httpRequest.setAttribute("currentAccount", currentAccount);
  httpRequest.setAttribute("addAccountUrl", addAccountUrl);
  httpRequest.setAttribute("accounts", accounts);

  chain.doFilter(request, response);
  
 }

 @Override
 public void destroy() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

}
```

```html
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AdminUserDetailsService.class)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class); 
 
 @Autowired 
 private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
 
 @Autowired
 public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {    
  //auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
 //auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);//commented for ease
  auth
  .inMemoryAuthentication()
   .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
  
  auth
  .inMemoryAuthentication()
   .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER");
 } 
 


 
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.authorizeRequests()
   
  //.antMatchers("/users","/users/**","/userpermission**","/userpermission/**").access("hasAnyRole('1')")
  .antMatchers("/userpermission**","/userpermission/**").access("hasAnyRole('1')")
  .antMatchers(AuthorizationParameters.TBX_CLIENT[0]).access("hasRole('"+AuthorizationParameters.TBX_CLIENT[1]+"')")
  .anyRequest().permitAll()
  .and()  
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
  .and()
  .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout") 
   .and()
   .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
  .and()
  .addFilterBefore(new DemoAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .csrf().disable();
   
 }

}
```

```html
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class Config {
 
  @Bean
  public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
   
   JedisConnectionFactory jediscon = new JedisConnectionFactory();
   jediscon.setHostName("192.168.1.210");
   jediscon.setPort(6379);
   jediscon.setPassword("");
   
   //return  new JedisConnectionFactory();
   return jediscon;
 }
  

}
```

What is the best way to implement the multiple user management or user switching with Spring Boot?

Comment: What do you mean with user switching and why implement your own instead of using the default `SwitchUserFilter` of Spring Security?

Comment: No I mean, how to change user account once it has been authenticated, we can switch through all the accounts from which we have already signed in. It is like switching signed in account?

Comment: See if this helps https://github.com/joshlong/bootiful-sessions/tree/master/users

Comment: @RobWinch Thanks a lot :) You have already helped me :)